# How to Bring Activity on Top from Service

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two activity 1)FrmHome which I have senTtoback 2)ScreenLock which I want to open from Service. When services calls the screen unlock the activity opens in background. When I tap on the application I can see the Screenlock Activity. I want ScreenLock Activity should come up on top without tapping on the app

And here is the service
and handler

```
public class FrmHome extends ActionBarActivity {

BroadcastReceiver mybroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {

//When Event is published, onReceive method is called
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "MyReceiver");

        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen ON");

            Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, ScreenLock.class);
            intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            startActivity(intent1);



        }
        else if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
            Log.i("[BroadcastReceiver]", "Screen OFF");
        }

  }
   };
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_frm_home);
    // registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON));
     registerReceiver(mybroadcast, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT));
}
}
```

My new activity opens in background. When I click on the app I can see the new Screenlock Activity. But it is not coming to front automaticlly

Answer (score 0):

You can bring the activity to front by calling `startActivity` again. In normal cases this starts a new instance of the activity, which might not be desirable. You can control that by setting the `launchMode` of the activity in `AndroidManifest.xml` (explained [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)). For example using `singleTop` should solve this. This way next time your service calls `startActivity`, the previous instance comes on top.

Comment: But I want to open a another activity(Screenlock) and I have sent back my main activity(FrmHome).

Comment: Sorry, the scenario you explain is not clear! You can use `startActivity` to open any activity you want. This function can be called both from a service or activity, and by default creates a new instance of the activity and shows it.

Comment: See I have two activity 1)FrmHome which I have senTtoback 2)ScreenLock which I want to open from Service. When services calls the screen unlock the activity opens in background. When I tap on the application I can see the Screenlock Activity. I want ScreenLock Activity should come up on top without tapping on the app